# When just declaring objects, it locates in stack?

Tags: java

I am very new to Java, and I am having difficult understanding memory allocation in Java. I have two main questions.

**first question**

When we write,

```
MyClass myObject;
```

If I just declare `myObject`, is the variable in stack memory?

**second question**

Assuming that `MyClass` has member variables and methods.

```
int temp1;
int temp2;

public void func1(){ ... };
...
```

Can I refer to the members? If so, how is that possible?

```
myObject.temp1;
```

I wonder if it's related to memory allocation.

Comment: If you do `MyClass myObject;` then `myObject` is null.

Comment: Where the reference `MyClass myObject;` is located in memory depends on where you put it. If it's a class member it will be on the heap, if it's a local variable in a method I'd say it's on the stack (although the referenced object would most likely be on the heap) but I'd have to verify that.

Comment: Accessing class members also depends on where you want to access them and on their visibility. In your case they're package private and thus will only be visible to code in the same package. But if `MyClass myObject;` would be declared outside the package then `myObject.temp1` wouldn't work since either `myObject` wouldn't be visible (it's also package private) or `temp1` wouldn't be visible. - In general you should grab a decent Java tutorial though which explains all this. Then play around with the code to see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @ScaryWombat not if it's a local variable.

Comment: @MauricePerry If it is a local variable, then according to my IDE it will not compile, due to being un-initialized.

Comment: @ScaryWombat to be precise, it would not compile it the variable was used before it's initialized.

Comment: @MauricePerry - You are correct, I was being very imprecise ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question:**

1. If the variable is declared outside a function, constructor,  initializer block or similar (method in particular), then that variable is stored by the class it is written into.

```java
    public class Main {
      protected int number=1; //I'm outside a method!
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Some stuff...
      }
      public String outsideMethod="I'm outside a method!";
    }
```

3. If the variable is declared in a method, then that variable is local and will be reduced to rubble after the method has completed its execution.

```java
    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value="I'm gonna get obliterated by the garbage collector later!";
        //Some moments later...
        value="Goodbye, see you at the other side of the garbage collector.";
      }
    }
```

**Second Question:**

1. You can refer to a class's member variables if they aren't set to `private` except if it's a `nested class`, you can take variables made by the parent class even if it's private!
2. You can refer to a class's variable in two ways.
3. First is statically, that's if a variable is declared to be `static`. Static means it stays in the memory longer, hence a "bad hog", a feature loved and hated by many.

```java
public /*or protected*/ static int number=100; //inside class named MyClass.
//Somewhere outside the class...
MyClass.number //access static variable statically.
```

4. Second is by initializing an `instance` of the object/class.

```java
public /*or protected*/ int number=100;
//Somewhere outside the class...
MyClass classy=new MyClass(...);
classy.number; //access variable by using an instance of the object.
```

5. I forgot, you can also access them somewhere inside the class they were declared in!

```java
final String lmao="lol";
String im_an_empty_string;
public static void main(String[] a) {
  im_an_empty_string=lmao;
}
```

**Others:**

1. If you don't know, final variables are var(s) that can't be changed no matter what.
2. The JVM optimizes operations with final var(s) by doing the operations in the memory itself! (A.K.A. statically.)
3. Lastly, don't worry about memory allocation! Java knows what it's doing.
4. Not unless you run out of physical memory and it throws an OOME.
5. OOME = OutOfMemoryException     P.S. It's an error that can't really be caught nicely.

---

Thanks for the additional info for Question 1&2, no. 1 [@user16320675](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16320675/user16320675)!

Comment: thanks for the details! I have an additional question.. for question 1 (if myObject is in a method), Is it possible to refer to the members of MyClass?

Comment: @Jini If your variable is inside a method, that variable can't be accessed outside the method itself. In other words, it's trapped there forever.

Comment: @Jini I misunderstood the question, if you do `MyClass classy=new MyClass()` then `classy.variable`, then yes, you can access the variables inside the method.

Comment: so it means that objects can't refer to them without initialize(instanctiate)? (Thanks so much for answering my additional questions :D i was really curious..)

Comment: @Jini Other objects cannot if they aren't initialized only IF the variables are not static.

Comment: For 1. in "**out of a method**" or similar, *method* means *method or similar*, including constructors and initializer blocks; For 2nd question, first point 4. `private` access is a bit more complicated regarding nested classes.